# Custom Post Type with has_archive ignores my custom archive and single template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to set up a new CPT called news (see code here: http://pastie.org/3148081) and I'm specifying the has_archive parameter.

I've set up a new template called archive-news.php and single-news.php but its not being used when I go to /news/ or the permalink on the site. Instead the default archive.php and single.php gets loaded.

I've flushed the rewrite rules but still does not work.

This is the first time I'm using the has_archive parameter but after lots of searching I still can't see what I doing wrong.

Hopefully it's just a stupid mistake somewhere that someone can spot for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom post type is `je_news`. This means that your single and archive files should be called **single-je_news.php** and **archive-je_news.php**.

The `has_archive` option enables you to change the archive url, but it doesn't override what the templates should be named.

Comment: Thanks @VelvetBlues I just realised this myself and posted at the same time as you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok feeling really stupid now!! I had used the following when registering the post type

```
register_post_type( 'je_news' , $args );
```

But named the archive file archive-news.php obviously it should be archive-je_news.php.

All working now.